# send windows audio stream to UPnP renderer

Tags: audio, upnp

I wonder if it is possible to send any audio coming out of a windows pc (e.g songs on youtube) to a UPnP renderer.

What I am trying to achieve is send all windows audio, not only tracks played through upnp clients, to the upnp server (popcorn hour) standing in the room next to me. I would imagine this implemented as a kind of windows audio driver.

Makes any sense?

Comment: [There are some answers to the same question on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/44629/application-to-stream-any-audio-to-upnp-device-xbox-360)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a directshow filter to get "what you hear"

http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualaudiodev/files/

Then the question remains on how to stream a directshow to UPNP.
I asked a question here on this. If needed you can follow it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It would take a driver to emulate a sound card to send the audio to, and then an aplication to send audio from the driver to a selected uPnp device.